# jsrender to render template with partials server side in node.js

Tags: node.js, templates, partials, jsrender, server-side-rendering

I can't work out the syntax for including a partial with jsrender in node.js.

I can **include** the partial as outlined in the documentation.

```
{{include tmpl='./views/partials/my_partial.html' /}}
```

This can be rendered and send to the browser

```
res.send(jsr.renderFile('./views/my_view.html'));
```

What I am trying to achieve is to define the partial inside a tag. I set the tag like so?

```
{{include my_partial /}}
```

And then in node.js extend the renderFile call like so:

```
res.send(jsr.renderFile('./views/partials/my_partial.html',
  {my_partial : tmpl='./views/partials/my_partial.html'}
));
```

No error but the include block is sent empty to the browser. :(

Answer (score 0):

I got there in the end by testing most possible syntax combinations.

The block/tag needs to be defined like so:

```
{{include tmpl=my_partial /}}
```

And then I can render the template with partial with this call.

```
res.send(jsr.renderFile('./views/partials/my_partial.html',
 {my_partial : './views/partials/my_partial.html'}
));
```